# Чи відмінюються назви сортів виноградів та вин?

Tags: власні-назви, запозичені-слова, відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Чи відмінюються назви сортів виноградів та вин, як-от: Піно Нуар, Совіньйон Блан, Каберне Совіньйон, Каберне Фран тощо? А також Сіра? І яке закінчення мають у родовому відмінку?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, додайте до свого запитання, що ви шукали і яких висновків ви вже дійшли.Також перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://goo.gl/XbjRge), [How to Ask](https://goo.gl/KuCfff), а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](https://goo.gl/wnuKFr). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть edit. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Comment: Усі іноземні слова практично не відмінюються через погане розуміння чи взагалі нерозуміння слова. Як тільки значення цього слова стане зрозумілим, то природньо приліпиться і відмінювання.

Answer (score 1):

Існують [великі винні сорти](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8) від них і походять назви деяких вин, таких як: Шардоне, Мерло, Піно Нуар.

Відповідно до сайту [Лінгвістичного порталу](http://www.mova.info/article.aspx?l1=118&DID=364):

> ... слово каберне - вино - середнього роду. Отже, вистояне каберне,
>   славетне каберне. Каберне як сорт винограду має чоловічий рід, тому
>   зелений каберне, стиглий каберне,..

Отже, якщо мова йде про назви цих сортів, то вони не відмінюються.

Це підтверджує і таблиця на сайті [Аztekium](http://aztekium.pl/find.py?lang=uk&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5).